# Add eCommerce to CiviCRM 4.7 on Drupal

Tags: drupal, webform-civicrm, commerce

We take Contributions and Event registrations via our website, and I'm hoping to add a simple eCommerce facility for resources we sell.

Just wondering what options might exist for adding this facility. We would want eCommerce customers to become CiviCRM contacts, but we're open to whether this happens at the front-end or via a back-end function (we're not anticipating large volumes of sales).

Our current toolset includes: CiviCRM 4.7, Drupal 7, CiviCRM Webforms, Entity Forms.

Answer (score 4):

There are many options/ways to go about doing this! One option would be to add Drupal Commerce module to your toolset. I use it for a number of projects - when I don't really have the need to track what users purchase in Civi**CRM** (e.g. school cafeteria order details (which child has which meal/drink every single day) and reservations for research institute with/without GPS rentals etc).

The integration you want depends on your needs (cliche...) - but the easiest - no code required one is to string together: Commerce, Commerce_[your_payment_processor], Webform, Commerce Webform, Webform CiviCRM, CiviCRM.

Commerce Webform will let you add Commerce Product Sku-s to your webform - and then these get pushed into the Commerce Cart for checkout; Once checked out -> Commerce Webform has a Rule that then goes back to the webform and mark skus->paid;

Webform CiviCRM will let you pull in info from a specific logged in Existing Contact - relationships etc.

Voila - here's a screenshot of a specific Order in a User's Orders tab:
Drink options are Drupal Commerce SKUs; Student info -> is pulled in from CiviCRM (relationship child of logged in existing Contact);

```
user/2/orders/32659
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Karin. Drupal Commerce is one option on my radar. How have you found the process of linking DC customers to CiviCRM contacts?

Comment: Hi Ken -> I've added a specific integration example - above; no code required!